# Scala: Getting a TypeTag on an inner type

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to get a `TypeTag` or `ClassTag` for an inner type to provide a `ClassTag` to a method with type parameters. Specicfically, I have

```
trait Baz
trait Foo { type Bar <: Baz }
```

and I'd like to do something like

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect._
typeTag[Foo#Bar] // or maybe
classTag[Foo#Bar]
```

but I get a 'no typetag available' error. My ultimate goal is to provide `ClassTag`s to something like this

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
class Doer[A,B]()(implicit ctA:ClassTag[A], ctB:ClassTag[B])
object Fooer extends Doer[Foo, Foo#Bar]()(classTag[Foo], classTag[Foo#Bar])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you can get type tags and class tags from inner types just fine. However, `Foo#Bar` is an abstract type. Neither type tags nor class tags can be acquired from abstract types. You can get a weak type tag instead:

```
scala> weakTypeTag[Foo#Bar]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[Foo#Bar] = WeakTypeTag[Foo#Bar]

scala> class Doer[A, B]()(implicit wttA: WeakTypeTag[A], wttB: WeakTypeTag[B])
defined class Doer

scala> new Doer[Foo, Foo#Bar]()
res2: Doer[Foo,Foo#Bar] = Doer@1994551a
```